# What effect does changing the process priority have in Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, process, taskmanager

If you go into Task Manager, right click a process, and set priority to Realtime, it often stops program crashes, or makes them run faster.

In a programming context, what does this do?

Comment: It does what is says it does... Give a higher (or lower) priority to a program. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It calls [SetPriorityClass()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686219%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

> Every thread has a base priority level determined by the thread's
>   priority value and the priority class of its process. The system uses
>   the base priority level of all executable threads to determine which
>   thread gets the next slice of CPU time. The SetThreadPriority function
>   enables setting the base priority level of a thread relative to the
>   priority class of its process. For more information, see Scheduling
>   Priorities.

Answer (score 1):

It tells the widows scheduler to be more or less greedy when allocating execution time slices to your process. Realtime execution makes it never yield execution (not even to drivers, according to MSDN), which may cause stalls in your app if it waits on external events but has no yielding of its own(like `Sleep`, `SwitchToThread` or `WaitFor[Single|Multiple]Objects`), as such using realtime should be avoided unless you *know* that the application will handle it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It works by changing the weight given to this process in the OS task scheduler. Your CPU can only execute one instruction at a time (to put it very, very simply) and the OS's job is to keep swapping instructions from each running process. By raising or lowering the priority, you're affecting how much time it's allotted in the CPU relative to other applications currently being multi-tasked.